# Remove firebase element by index or class

Tags: android, firebase

The Java API for [firebase](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/) doesn't seem to be too clear. I add objects to my firebase like:

```
Food foodObj=new Food();
foodObj.setValue("name",food);//food is a string
foodObj.setValue("color",color);
myFirebaseRef.push().setValue(foodObj.getKeysValues());
```

I show every element in from firebase in a `listView`. On a long click I want to delete the selected item. I can get the index and the object from the front end `arrayList`.

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

         final int temp = position;
         new AlertDialog.Builder(FridgeActivity.this)
              .setMessage("Do you want to delete this item?")
              .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                       Log.d(tag, "should delete:" + Integer.toString(temp));
                       Food mess = fridge.get(temp);

                    }
                 })
            .setNegativeButton("No", null)
            .show();
        return true;
    }
});
```

I have not figured out how delete `mess`. I've tried `myFirebaseRef.removeVal()` but that removes everything from the database.

Comment: What is `getKeysValues()` returning? You don't need to save a Map to firebase, you can just save a Bean object.

Comment: you need to get a FirebaseRef to the specific element you would like to remove and then use removeValue() on it

Comment: @RonHarlev how do I get a specific element? Some elements have the same name.

Comment: @depperm Ha, what are the chances. I live only minutes away from you.

Comment: As @ChadBingham answered, you'll need to track the key for each object or position so that you can call `ref.child(key).remove()`. For some inspiration on how to do that, you may want to look at [FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/) - our open-source library that simplifies using Firebase in Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you right, your dataset looks like this (in your Firebase Dashboard):

```
yourApp:
    food -
        FiReBaSeGenErAtEdKeY   - // Mapped to object Food 
                               - name: "food"
                               - color: "color"
        MoReGenErAtEdKeYs2     +
        MoReGenErAtEdKeYs3     +
        MoReGenErAtEdKeYs4     +
```

You can *only* delete values by using the keys, and more specifically, all the keys to create a "path" to the object. For instance, if you wanted to delete the Food object `FiReBaSeGenErAtEdKeY`, **you need to know its path**. In this case  your path will be `<your_ref>/food/FiReBaSeGenErAtEdKeY`. To do this:

```
 myFirebaseRef
     .child("food") //the food branch
     .child("FiReBaSeGenErAtEdKeY") // the key of the object
     .removeValue();  // delete
```

Or if you wanted to remove `color` value, your path will be `<your_ref>/food/FiReBaSeGenErAtEdKeY/color`

```
myFirebaseRef
         .child("food") //the food branch
         .child("FiReBaSeGenErAtEdKeY") // the key of the object
         .child("color") //actually using "color" because that is the name of the key. This will remove the value, and because there are no more values, the key is empty, therefore it will be deleted too. 
         .removeValue();  // delete
```

It can be hard to get the key after-the-fact. There are ways to get it from the [DataSnapshot](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/api/#datasnapshot_methods), but I like to setup my object like this:

```
public class Food {
     private String key;      // add the key here
     private String name;
     private String color;
     //other fields 

     public Food(){ /* empty constructor needed by Firebase */ }

     //Add all of your accessors 

}
```

Then, when you want to create/save the food object:

```
String key = myFireBaseRef.push().getKey();
Food food = new Food();
food.setKey(key);
food.setColor(color);
food.setName(name);

//Then to save the object:
myFirebaseRef
    .child("food") //move to the "food" branch
    .child(food.getKey())
    .setValue(food);
```

---

References:

- [Firebase Guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/understanding-data.html)
- [Firebase API reference](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/api/#datasnapshot_methods)